# Why i'm getting exception when trying to get all images form hard disk to a List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 constructor:

```
imageslist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select(path => new Bitmap(path))
    .Select(bmp => ResizeImage(bmp, 100, 100))
    .ToList();
```

The exception is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean userInitiatedDispose)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTask.SpoolStopAndGo[TInputOutput,TIgnoreKey](QueryTaskGroupState groupState, PartitionedStream`2 partitions, SynchronousChannel`1[] channels, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.DefaultMergeHelper`2.System.Linq.Parallel.IMergeHelper<TInputOutput>.Execute()
       at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute()
       at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput, ParallelMergeOptions options, TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Boolean isOrdered, CancellationState cancellationState, Int32 queryId)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitionedStream)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping, QuerySettings settings)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping, QuerySettings settings)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.ScanQueryOperator`1.ScanEnumerableQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings)
       at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.OpenQuery()
       at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.ToList[TSource](ParallelQuery`1 source)
       at LoadingImages.Form1..ctor() in D:\C-Sharp\LoadingImages\LoadingImages\LoadingImages\Form1.cs:line 29
       at LoadingImages.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\LoadingImages\LoadingImages\LoadingImages\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2147024809
       Message=Parameter is not valid.
       Source=System.Drawing
       StackTrace:
            at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
            at LoadingImages.Form1.<>c.<.ctor>b__6_0(String path) in D:\C-Sharp\LoadingImages\LoadingImages\LoadingImages\Form1.cs:line 31
            at System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2.SelectQueryOperatorEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TOutput& currentElement, TKey& currentKey)
            at System.Linq.Parallel.SelectQueryOperator`2.SelectQueryOperatorEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TOutput& currentElement, TKey& currentKey)
            at System.Linq.Parallel.StopAndGoSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork()
            at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work()
            at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused)
            at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__10_0(Object o)
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
       InnerException:
```

Not sure why it happen and how to solve it.

Comment: What's `dir`? Is it a string, and if so which? show the initialization.

Comment: [This may be of interest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780870/using-asparallel-parellel-foreach-guidelines)

Comment: The exception listing appears clipped. Could you post complete one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the several scenarios using your code + a mock for resize:

1) Took some 700 random bitmaps - works fine

2) Added a very large bitmap (12K x 12K) - works fine

3) Added a fake bitmap (some text file renamed to .bmp) - fails with your error

In order to find out which is actually giving the error, the following code can be used:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap bmp, int width, int height)
{
    return bmp;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var imageslist = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\BmpTest", "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .AsParallel()
        .Select(path =>
            {
                Bitmap ret = null;
                try
                {
                    ret = new Bitmap(path);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                     // put breakpoint here and check path
                }
                return ret;
            })
        .Select(bmp => ResizeImage(bmp, 100, 100))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting exception. It's holding for some time then the program freeze not responde then it throw the exception.

Comment: Now i checked the task manager i see that vshost32.exe is taking 1.3GB of memory usage ! when running the program. I guess that's what make later the exception.

Comment: I will add the exception full message to my question in a second.

Comment: Now it didn't throw the exception but only 11 images were in the List and all the others are null.

Comment: There are 1431 images in the list.

Comment: I must add that some of the files the images on the hard disk size are 3MB and some between 5-6MB and they are 24 bit.

Comment: You should try processing less images at once. You can use Take function for a start to have a working case.

Comment: I guess the problem is with the memory maybe sinze the files too big.

Comment: How do i use the take ? I tried after the AsParallel() i did .Take<10> but got error.

Comment: Try taking first and then parallelize fetched items.

Comment: Working with the Take(). And the ResizeImage method it should be empty ? It return the same image size resolution.

Comment: No,  use your resize function. I have used a dummy one to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the problem is your ResizeImage method that you called. Maybe it is not thread safe. You should check your implemantation of this method or you can share the method's implemantation with us.

ps: I couldn't comment that's why i had to write as answer.

Comment: According to the stack trace, the exception is thrown by Bitmap's constructor. Also, threading is not relevant for this code.

Comment: Yes i couldn't notice.that point. In this case the exception may relevant about memory allocation of bitmap if he has so much png files.

Comment: Also at second point you said it is not about threading. But as i know AsParallel() is working multithread. [link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) @CodeCaster

Comment: Yes, `AsParallel` can execute on multiple threads, but that is not relevant here. The bimaps instances are not accessed in a cross-thread way.